# Is this statement trivial or requires some work?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

[image]

My question regards the last two lines of that proof. Is such statement trivial or does it require some work?

My thought is that since the series with the $n-1$ in the power can be shifted so as to have $z^n$ the $n$ will have different initial value in the series and removing any finite number of values of power series does no change the radius of convergence.

Do we have to be rigorous and prove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If 
$$
\limsup |a_n|^{1/n} = \limsup |n a_n|^{1/n}
\tag1$$
(possibly $\infty$), then
$$
\frac{1}{\limsup |a_n|^{1/n}} = \frac{1}{\limsup |n a_n|^{1/n}}
$$
with the conventions $1/0 = \infty$ and $1/\infty = 0$.
Hadamard's formula says that
$$
\frac{1}{\limsup |a_n|^{1/n}}
$$
is the radius of convergence of the power series $\sum a_n z^n$, and
$$
\frac{1}{\limsup |n a_n|^{1/n}}
$$
is the radius of convergence of the power series $\sum n a_n z^n$.
So it follows from $(1)$ that $\sum a_n z^n$ and $\sum n a_n z^n$
have the same radius of convergence.
Next, the series $\sum n a_n z^n$ converges if and only if
$\sum n a_n z^{n-1}$ converges.  So the radius of convergence
of $\sum n a_n z^n$ is the same as the radius of convergence of
$\sum n a_n z^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

The response to "it is obvious" is often "why is it obvious?" Always prove it rigorously to yourself first. If you have to think about how to prove it rigorously, it is not obvious. It can be hard to tell whether something will be obvious to somebody who hasn't thought about the particular issue as much as you have. If in doubt include the proof.

This particular one is not obvious to me, though I am a little rusty in this field.